# STR_TO_DATE() returns wrong data from right format

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, formatting

Using MySQL 5.7, it's pretended a conversion from strings representing four-digit year followed by two-digit month with no any other character in the middle.

For example, running the following statement

```sql
SELECT str_to_date('202105','%Y%m');
```

What is returned: `160101` being January 1601 instead of May 2021. The required [arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) seem correct considering the [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in cause.

Comment: In MySQL 5.6 and earlier it returns `2021-05-00`, it returns `NULL` in later versions. There's no day 0 in the month, so that was apparently a bug that they fixed.

Comment: You need to specify the day as well, otherwise it won't work in MySQL 8.0+.

Comment: Note: the MySQL version was changed.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your exact result on [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.com), but I did see it creates a `null` instead of the expected date. What you can do is append a '01' to get a better date literal:

```
SELECT str_to_date(concat('202105', '01'),'%Y%m%d');
```

See it here:

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbArVsLF6BVDGSrYdy8geP/0

Comment: I run it like that, and I get ```16010101```.

Comment: @NelsonA.Morais What exact version of MySql, and how are you observing the result... because again, you can try it and see on the link I provided.

Comment: Understood. Meanwhile, when it's applied ```UNIX_TIMESTAMP()``` function to the output, it's returned the July fifth of 1970. So, I assume it's adding 20210501 seconds to the Unix epoch and then ```STR_TO_DATE()``` takes no effect independently of what is provided as ```str``` and ```format```.

Comment: I'm working on MySQL Workbench 8.0, and after checking server status from the current connection where I've tested it on, I see the version 5.7.6 after all.

Comment: Anyway, I tried to run it in both versions (8.0 and 5.7) from your link, and the output is OK. However, the problem persists.

Comment: Your server is configured with some a-typical options, then, and you'll need to work around it.

Comment: The server works from a CData SQL Gateway solution with CData Excel ODBC Driver. Very specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the day as well, otherwise it won't work in MySQL 8.0+.

You need all parts of the date i.e. year, month and day must be specified for the function to operate properly.

```
# Incorrect Code:
SELECT str_to_date('202105','%Y%m');

# Correct Code:
SELECT str_to_date('20210501','%Y%m%d');
```

Outputs

```
2020-05-01
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: I've run into this too, sad since the doc explicitly shows this working "Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to 0:"

Comment: I run the correct code, and I get ```16010101```.

Comment: The MySQL version is 5.7 after all.